# Login failed using check_mssql_server.py

Tags: sql-server, nagios, pymssql

We are trying to monitor MSSQL server parameters using the python plugin `check_mssql_server.py`. The SQL server we are trying to access uses the standard windows authentication (separate SQL authentication is not required) and the windows id is in the format `my-domain\userid`.

### When we execute the plugin we endup with different error messages like.

> SQL Server message 18452, severity 14, state 1, line 1: Login failed
>   for user 'my-domainuserid'. The user is not associated with
>   a trusted SQL Server connection. DB-Lib error message 18452, severity
>   14: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server
>   DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9: Adaptive Server connection
>   failed

### when we use the user id as my-domain\userid (via macro in resource.cfg file)

```
DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:
Adaptive Server connection failed
```

### when we use the user id as "my-domain\userid" (via macro in resource.cfg file)

My DB admin has confirmed that they could use the same userid to query the server locally and suggested it to be an issue with the plugin/nagios.

We are using Nagios XI 2012R1.8

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. Your question suggests that your SQL Server is configured for Windows authentication only, but the [documentation](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer/Check-MSSQL-Server-Centric-Status/details) for the plugin suggests that only SQL authentication is supported. Can you clarify that, and show the login details that you're using to connect? You also haven't mentioned which OS you're running Nagios on or which version of SQL Server you have.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: This is now possible following the instructions found on the Nagios KB located here
https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-xi-mssql-wizards-adaptive-server-connection-failed.html

---

The check_mssql_server.py plugin will NOT work with Windows Authentication and requires SQL authentication.

As of this time I do not believe anyone has created a MSSQL plugin that can use Windows Authentication.